# How to bargain lead role when I'm a newly joined employee

Tags: salary, promotion

I'm working as a full stack developer joined marely 7 months ago(I have good performance & experience as freelance developer - more than 3 years, But had to join as fresher due to "conventions")  in a small scale company. Due to some management issues, most of my seniors have resigned from the job. One senior who was handling most of the work for the company's dream project is also on notice.

Now as the company is about to have its market establishment(Already have had initial funding). There's basically no worthy one who can act as right hand of the CEO. The CEO has offered me to lead this project & make sure that everything goes well.

The reason previous senior who was doing all this has left is the requirements change suddenly. He often has to work on weekends & push more than 9 hours a day. However, this looks like an opportunity it has some hard requirements. I was thinking to leave the company as the pay scale is moderate & I already have received better offers.

The proposal given to me was totally verbal & no benefits were mentioned. I have to get an answer tomorrow. If I deny this might lead me to face unintended situation in the company. Please give me an advice.

**Edit**
The proposal includes a commitment to lead the project till atleast 1 year.

Comment: So...what is the question?

Comment: Akash, an anonymous user proposed an edit which I voted to Reject because it changed a number of the details in your question. If this was actually you, please log in with your original account so that you can edit the question. If you have accidentally created two accounts, you follow the [instructions on how to merge them](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

until you have a signed offer letter from another company with a start date, you should treat your current role as if you will be there forever.

If you would like to stay but under better circumstances, get any promises or new perks in writing.

Comment: If you don't recieve a written offer from the other company you should ask for a new contract with the benefits you're looking for, it's a CEO you need to tell him directly things without BS that's how executives do stuff, just tell him you need a new contract to proceed with the project

Comment: @AkashRajput  Compile a short list of things you would stay for. I.E. More Vacation, Higher Pay, Company car, access to Company Jet/Helicopter/Jetpack, Work From home days, Stock in company, Profit Sharing, etc.    Then bring that list to the CEO, let him know you would be happy to become the CTO, CFO, CSO etc at the company along side him for the items on your list.  Be reasonable, negotiate enough so you both feel like you won.   Then once you have made an agreement, ask him to put it in writing and ask that they new benefits take affect by the next pay period.

Comment: He won't give me a jetpack for sure. @jesse It eats too much fuel

Comment: @RobertoTorres seems sensible.